# Cannot POST "PHP file" PHP

Tags: php, html, post, error-handling

I'm trying to make a login page to learn basic PHP , first i want my seperate PHP file to store the input of the HTML file ( with a form ) , but when I press the button ( to trigger the POST to the PHP script ) I keep getting an unpleasing error.

Ive searched trough SO / internet , and i found similar people with my problem , but not the right solution for this problem ( atleast for my case )
Im pretty certain the problem has to do with structure / mapping , but I dont have a clue

my user login page :

```
  <form action="VerkoperApi.php" method="post">
    <p>Chose a username</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="Username" name="Username">
        <p>Choose a password</p>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="Password" name="Password">
        <p>Repeat password</p>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" id="RepeatPassword" name="RepeatPassword">

        <p id="ErrorMessage"></p>

        <p>Please enter e-mail address</p>
        <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail address" id="Email" name="Email">
        <p></p>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
```

My Php file :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "root" , "" , "MyDBName");


if ($link == false)
{
die("No connection")
}
else    
{

$uname = $_POST['Username'];
$upass = $_POST['Password'];
$umail = $_POST['Email'];



}
?>
```

Im working in Framework 7 , and my .php file is in the same folder as my html page , so in my folder you will find  : /Framework7-1.6.5/dist/index.html & /Framework7-1.6.5/dist/VerkoperApi.php

this is the error i'm getting : 
Cannot POST /Framework7-1.6.5/dist/VerkoperApi.php

If you need any more information , feel free to ask!

Comment: Using the `mysql_` functions is extremely bad.  They were deprecated in PHP 5 and removed in PHP 7.  [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for more information.

Comment: Thanks , but this solves a diffrent problem. i'm still not able to POST the data from my HTML to my PHP file

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use it to learn basic PHP, you can create values for the $uname, $pass and $umail variable instead of using $_POST['name'], but i can see you created a database for your learning so you have to create a table which will contain the users name, password and email and then use your php code to check if user details are true or false, and then redirect/show a successful message or take logged user to a specific page.

*Or you can try this basic login code;*

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('your database details');
    session_start();

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];

                $ardp_login_query = mysqli_query($link "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password='$password'");
            $rows = mysqli_num_rows($link);
            if($rows > 0) {

                // session properties
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

                // take user back to index page
                header("location: home.php?user=$username");
            } else {
                echo = '<font color="red">Login failed, check username or password</font>';
            } 
        mysqli_close($link);
    } 
?>
```

and you also forgot to close your `<form></form>` tag

Comment: Yes i do have the database , but I'd like the user to register here , and then later i want to use the user's input to be in the database , not what i chose , am I wrong trying to POST the variables like this? as i'm understanding , you POST the variables the user types in the html to the PHP script , where you can later add these with sql to the DB?

Comment: i think you need to search on how to create a login page using php

Comment: I did , that is what got me in this situation

Comment: That's definitely what he is doing, the problem is he can't access those POST variables

Comment: I didnt forget to close it , its just not included in the example , I still can't access the variables

Comment: Let me correct myself in the code shown , also , i just wanted to keep you an update that this isnt the right solution , ive actually been searching for hours , but i think i'm going to solve this problem with a diffrent solution , because i'm getting a headache :-)

Comment: funny, please remove the down vote you are actually increasing more to my ban

Comment: I dont understand what you think is comical here , plus I haven't voted down on your answer , but i'll give you a vote up :) By the way , the soloution you gave me is to check if it excists , Im trying to put it Inside the DB